# What is this filter/post-production called?

Tags: filter, saturation

This is the thumbnail of a music clip, and I was wondering how to achieve this look on a picture but have no idea what to even look for:

[image]

It could be just a type of camera and/or photographic film.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a high contrast black and white image which has been colourised. If filters were used, probably not a single one but a combination of effects, possibly even some hand colouring.

Here's one method:

Using software such as GIMP or Photoshop, start with a normal colour image. Duplicate the layer, and desaturate the bottom layer, using the Monomixer (in GIMP), or the Black and White filter (in Photoshop), bumping up the reds to wash out the skin tones. Then do a levels adjustment to make it a high contrast black and white image.

An example

[image]

Then select the top coloured layer and set the blending mode to Burn.

An example (this was made in GIMP, but will work in Photoshop too).

[image]

You could refine it further by adding another layer, and paint on it to colour more areas manually, and set the blending mode to multiply with reduced opacity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to get the whitening (or chalk) effect, but not the facemaking to an existing photo, you simply select the area which you want to be affected and insert a couple of adjustment layers which **both** have the same selection as layer mask (see NOTE1).

My original image (an ambassador, captured from a local news site), the adjustment layers are disabled:

[image]

The curves layer increases the contrast by lifting lower midtones. The lips are out of the selection area which makes them dark red. If the ambassador used a dark red lipstick, the selection could well include also the lips. The effect of the curves layer:

[image]

As you see the selection of the lips affects radically the apparent mood of the character. To avoid lawsuits its a good idea to make clear that the result presents only image editor's imagination or lack of talent, not the truth.

The selected area is whitened by decreasing the saturation of reds by increasing their brightness.

[image]

The previous contrast lift compensates the caused contrast loss beforehand. The color range of the Hue/Saturation prevent the effect to whiten possible bright colored eyes and reduces the complexity of the needed layer mask. This image didn't have such problem, the eyes were grey and there was no colored make-up.

If the skin tone happened to be a southern one, the color range, of course, should be more on orange than red.

NOTE1: This selection was easy. The quick selection tool made it except the lips were subtracted manually with the lasso. The hair wasn't here a big problem, not at least in making the selection. Somehow richer images may require making the selection by drawing a path. The layer mask appeared automatically when the selection was ON and the adjustment layer was inserted.